# How do I get rid of Wine drive?

Tags: wine

I had installed Wine application then I removed it , but it still shows up when I do a virus scan.

I want to know how to completely remove the Wine drive.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'it still shows up'? Are you talking about configuration files? Menu entries? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

From the terminal

```
rm -rf ~/.wine
```

You can also do the same from Nautilus. Open your home and press Ctrl+h, locate the folder `.wine` and delete it. Dont forget to empty your trash bin if you use this method.

Both methods will delete your Wine bottles and everything in them, beware if you have any documents or anything you want to save inside a bottle.

Comment: That will most definitely remove Wine and all the content in it.

Comment: That's the spirit ;)